# Flutter Firebase How many collection exist in each document?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question that i didnt solve it since cosmos.

I have a collection in Firebase like this:

[image]

I can query `2023 collection` its okay. But inside these documents `(Haziran,Mayis)`, there is no field. There is just another sub collections.Inside that subcollections (*ps. 07.06.2023*), there is another documents with fields.

I just want to do know how many collection exist inside each document in `2023 collection` ?
Simplyfying, How can i know how many collection exist inside of `Haziran document` ?

I have come this far;

```
 final collectionRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('2023')
                    .get();

                for (var month in collectionRef.docs) {
                  print(month.id);
                }
```

This gives me a 2023 Collection's documents name which they are Haziran and Mayis. I can sense if there is a way to do this it should be with for loop one by one..

Comment: Firestore web and mobile clients don't offer any API to list or count collections or subcollections.  You can maintain a count yourself in another document, or use one of the backend SDKs to get a list and count its size.  I will point out that if your database design frequently requires client to know a number of collections or subcollections, you like don't have a good model for firestore.  Varible-sized lists of things should either be document array fields or simply documents under a single known collection.